# How to decrease POST and GET queue in high load time?

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, plugins, get

I have created a wordpress website to collect student's attendance. To do so, I've installed a plugin and all data are sent to google sheet.
The problem is that when all students enter and tried to submit their attendance, around hundred users go live at one moment which leads to a very high load to my website, and mostly they get error 503 or sometimes 500.
To solve this problem, some solutions cross my mind:

1. Of course, I can upgrade my server and hardware resources. However, I'm using a shared hosting and it is very costly to do.
2. I installed another plugin, and tried to handle the situation with two different and separate plugins in one page, however, as I know, they both use one GET and POST function which is the core of wordpress and it does't matter if I use different plugin simultaneously, they need to wait. Am I right?
3. I created two mirror page for my attendance to direct users to each page randomly, hopefully it reduces the page load. However, for form submitting the scenario is still the same since the forms in different pages also use same POST and GET.

Please give me some advice if there is any other solution. For now, I just inserted a google form as an alternative. However, I guess there is maybe another possible solution to handle inside the site not using external form provider.
Here is the site: [Attendance website](http://rafiee.net/attendance)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 'Disconnected' architecture?

Ideally, all the attendance should be sent to a high performance queue and then your app can read it at its own pace.